# How to show satellite view of Android mapview only

Tags: android, android-mapview, satellite

At middle of 2011 set mapView.setSattelite(true) will only show satellite view, but recently we find the same set will also show with roads and names above satelliete view. 
   May be it's very useful in other country, but in China, when add roads and names above satelliete view, the roads are not on the right position.

Can some one tell me how to remove roads and names above satelliete view?

How to show satellite view of Android mapview only.

I read Class MapView:

`setSatellite(boolean on)`
          Sets the map mode to "satellite" mode, loading tiles of aerial imagery with roads and names superimposed.

Can someone help me out? Help us live on Mars！

Answer (score 3):

```
public void myClickHandler(View target) {
        switch(target.getId()) {
        /*case R.id.zoomin:
            mapView.getController().zoomIn();
            break;
        case R.id.zoomout:
            mapView.getController().zoomOut();
            break;*/
        case R.id.sat:
            this.mapView.setSatellite(true);
            break;
        case R.id.street:
            this.mapView.setStreetView(true);
            break;
        case R.id.traffic:
            this.mapView.setTraffic(true);
            break;
        case R.id.normal:
            this.mapView.setSatellite(false);
            this.mapView.setStreetView(false);
            this.mapView.setTraffic(false);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        // The following line should not be required but it is,
        // at least up til Froyo.
        this.mapView.postInvalidateDelayed(2000);
    }
```

i believe you need **setStreetView**, even though it says it's deprecated it works ok for me

```
@Deprecated
public void setStreetView(boolean on)
Deprecated. Street view availability highlighting is no longer supported. This method operates as a no-op. 

Control whether Street View availability (blue outlines) is shown on the map. This is incompatible with Traffic indicators, so they will be deactivated if necessary. Street View availability can be drawn over map tiles or over satellite tiles; however, they are optimized for map tiles.
```

Comment: I used setStreetView(false) with setSatellite(true) before,but it's not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this can be accomplished, because when you are using google mapview, the images come from google themself for road map and sattelite map, unless they do an update for the API to show only sattelite images without road names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We hope google add new feature of API about something like setRoadMap(boolean on) , it's very useful to us. Do you know how to contact google mapview engineer by email? We want to ask them for help.  By the way, do we have other options to get satellite view only?

Comment: Still not find the solution. Here is unclosed issue [http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22405](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22405)